# Multithreading - Schedule neverending runnables in Threadpools

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable

I cannot seem to find a good answer to my problem:
Suppose I have a certain amount of runnables of the form

```
public class NeverendingRunner implements Runnable {

//...

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        //Do what you have to do

        //At the end of the iteration, get back in queue
    }
}
```

If I use thread pools to run these, they will never left the execution, obviously.
I'd like to schedule them like in the comment I've made at the end of the iteration.

E.G.: I have 2 Runnables with infinite loops (and they have to be infinite for the task they do) and a treadpool of 1 thread (for simplicity). I want these two loops to alternate the usage of the thread. The Runnables don't know each other.

I don't know if this is even possible to be done.

Thank you for any help or suggest

EDIT: Jost solution solved the problem offering the scalability I was aiming for. Thank you.

Comment: hard to say without knowing about the nature of those tasks, but it does not look like a good fit for runnables and threadpools

Comment: The nature of the tasks are different, but one iteration is quite fast in each of them. Basically a scan of an array, or an update of some variables. Data are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), remove the infinite loop and enable the two Runnables to reschedule themselves to the executor. This code snippet might help:

```
public class Task implements Runnable
{
    private ReentrantLock lock;
    private ExecutorService executor;

    public Task(ExecutorService executor)
    {
        this.executor=executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        //do some stuff
        //...

        lock.lock();
        executor.execute(this);
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Note: I have not tried this example - but in general it should work. The lock ensures that the executor doesn't start with `run()` before it was finished (sounds a bit weird - but makes sense in the case of more than one thread in the pool).

*Jost

Comment: However, be careful when using private locks: they will not lock anything when creating a new instance of Task for another job.

Comment: If you need to process multiple iterations within one execution of `run()` use a for-loop - so you reduce the expensive task-switching, especially for short iterations.

Comment: @RalfH Yes you are absolutely  right - locks are tricky. There might be better solutions concerning the lock, but they reduce readability of this example. As I said it is a snippet ;-).

Comment: I really like this solution, it exactly centers the point of my problem. Also the For-Loop suggested by jost for short tasks is a good idea... I'll implement it in the next few minutes and let you know. If you have any other suggest on this solution, feel free to share.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine something like this

```
    final Runnable task1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("task1");
            }
        }
    };
    final Runnable task2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("task2");
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for(;;) {
                task1.run();
                task2.run();
            }
        };
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The below code may achieve this but its not the best implementation**

```
CyclicBarrier run1 = new CyclicBarrier(2);
CyclicBarrier run2 = new CyclicBarrier(2);

public class RUN1 implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        //Do what you have to do
        //At the end of the iteration, get back in queue
         run1.await();
         run2.await();
    }
}
}

public class RUN2 implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
         run1.await();
        //Do what you have to do
        //At the end of the iteration, get back in queue
         run2.await();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the runnables do not knwo each other, they probably don't have to be run by the same thread. In any case, it is often better to think in terms of runnables and their possible dependencies than in threads. If there is a real reason for them to run alternating (maybe even alternating at defined switch-points, then perhaps they (or what happens inside them) *should* know of each other.

Normally, when running independent runnables in independent threads, the OS scheduling takes care of alternating them already. Since they are neverending, make sure you wrap the loops in try/catch(InterruptedException) blocks to be able to kill the threads nicely.

Answer (score 0):

See method loopAct() in the file [DataflowVariable](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/blob/master/df4j-core/src/com/github/rfqu/df4j/core/DataflowVariable.java). It is overhead for your case, but idea is simple: keep a boolean variable showing if the task is working; when the task finishes all jobs, it turns off the variable and exits; when another thread supplies a job to the task, and the variable shows it is not working, it turns on the variable and sends the task to the executor. This way you'll never get the task executed by more than one thread simultaneously.